# Why does xamarin pcl build takes so long

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, msbuild

I'm currently working on a **Xamarin pcl** project in visual studio 2017 with the platforms **UWP** and **Android**. Until a month ago the building of the project goes fast but nu each time I change something it takes about 100 seconds before it completes its build.

My architecture:
I have one PCL project with UWP and Android.

This project has 4 Library projects as dlc's.

1 of the libs has another lib as dlc.

It doesn't matter where my change is, it always takes around 100 seconds before it builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your project(s) with MSBuild `PerformanceSummary` or `Diagnostic` level logging and at the end of the build log you will receive two performance summaries; `Target` and `Task`. From there you will be able to focus on want actually is taking the most time...

i.e.

```
Target Performance Summary:
      ~~~~
      117 ms  _ResolveLibraryProjectImports              1 calls
      229 ms  _CollectAdditionalResourceFiles            1 calls
      271 ms  _ResolveAssemblies                         1 calls
      360 ms  _SetLatestTargetFrameworkVersion           1 calls
      362 ms  _CopyIntermediateAssemblies                1 calls
      422 ms  _CopyMdbFiles                              1 calls
      437 ms  _CreateBaseApk                             1 calls
      441 ms  _CreateAdditionalResourceCache             1 calls
      518 ms  _GenerateJavaStubs                         1 calls
      570 ms  _LinkAssembliesNoShrink                    1 calls
      602 ms  _UpdateAndroidResgen                       1 calls
      ~~~~

Task Performance Summary:
      ~~~~
      359 ms  ResolveSdks                                1 calls
      381 ms  CreateItem                               181 calls
      437 ms  CreateAdditionalLibraryResourceCache       1 calls
      495 ms  GenerateJavaStubs                          1 calls
      519 ms  Copy                                       9 calls
      567 ms  LinkAssemblies                             1 calls
     1134 ms  Csc                                        1 calls
     1915 ms  Aapt                                       3 calls
     2097 ms  Javac                                      1 calls
     ~~~~
```

Re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/

Comment: This is the largest two are but I don't know if this if fixable?
1>    71555 ms  BuildNativePackage                         1 calls 
2>    70317 ms  LoggerBasedExecTask                        1 calls

Comment: @TiesTheunissen `BuildNativePackage` is when you are building a native `appx` package. This *normally* is CPU bound (and disk bound to a lesser degree, especially if you have an SSD) as it is invoking the compiler tool chain to AOT your IL to native x86/arm code. You can watch the task manager during a BuildAll to determine if it is cpu or disk bound...but not much you can do unless new hardware (CPU and/or a SSD drive) is in your future.

Comment: It uses indeed the CPU. But the using of the CPU is an avarage of 40%. I have a Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20 Ghz and an SSD. So if the CPU was building at 100% it makes sence but if the avarage is 40% it isn't wright?

Comment: @TiesTheunissen The Native/AOT compiler is not completely multi-threaded, so single core speed and cache size is king. Debug configuration uses CoreCLR so IL is fine, but when you switch to Release builds, native is required, MS does have a bunch of tips, like using the `NETNative.Analyzer` to constantly check your code while in debug mode, etc..  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/index